# urlencoding of the_title() doesn't work?

Tags: php, urls

hey guys,
`<?php urlencode(the_title()); ?>`doesn't take effect.

this is my entrie line of code:

`<li><a href="mailto:?subject=<?php urlencode(the_title()); ?>&amp;body=<?php the_permalink(); ?>">e-mail</a></li>`

I don't want to have spaces in the_title(). Why does urlencode not work for me?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The `the_title()` echo the title. You must use `get_the_title()` instead. get_the_title() returns the title as string. Use

```
<? echo urlencode(get_the_title()) ?>
```

Comment: +1 because I forget the `get` almost everytime I use these functions :)

Comment: what do I have to do when I want to use this outside of the loop? e.g. in my sidebar?