# How do I urlencode() the blog description?

Tags: description

I have a series of share buttons, each one using a short URL (using Ozh's Yourls plugin) and a page title (as found on [urlencoding of the_title() doesn't work?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14114/urlencoding-of-the-title-doesnt-work)) and some require a description.  How do I put the blog description, encoded correctly, into my URL?

Comment: Perhaps you could show us a screenshot, or some code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
echo urlencode(get_bloginfo('description'));
```